# how can I use datetime-local without AM/PM?

Tags: html, input

I'd like to use the following code:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="date" value="" />
```

and would like it to be without AM/PM and instead be 24 hour based. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you ok with using JavaScript to handle it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`datetime-local`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#local-date-and-time-state-%28type=datetime-local%29) input type specifies a local time without time zone, and the internal representation of the value is in ISO 8601 conformant format, which has no AM/PM. It is left to implementations to decide what localized format might be used in the *user interface*. Whether they have AM/PM designator is outside the author’s control.

In my environment, of the browsers I regularly use, only Chrome has real support to `datetime-local`. It’s qualitatively questionable (using ISO 8601 format), but the point is that has no AM/PM, or even a possibility of entering it. Your mileage will vary, by the language of your browser and/or operating system settings.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it server based OS shows this with AM/PM and client OS without.