# How to change format from 12hrs to 24 hrs in html5 datetime picker?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I am using datetime picker from Html5.

```html
      <input id="datetime"  type="datetime-local">
```

But It is containing 12 Hrs time with A.M or P.M, But I want to set 24 hrs place of A.M, P.M.

I am refering this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

My problem is only I want to set 24 hrs in time.

Comment: Am I missing something or it is `24hrs` format and not 12hr in the code snippet.

Comment: @Denisx It is 24 hrs format. Please run my snippet then you will get clear. I don't want to AM PM format, I want only 00 to 24 hrs

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523060/html5-time-inputs-shows-12-hours/13523302

Comment: @void I already looked. It is only for time. Not for date and time. And also it is setting AM PM. Against I don't want to AM PM

Comment: @VSH that is why I am not marking it duplicate, but is one and the same thing.

Comment: @void thanks. Both are viseversa. It is not duplicate.

Comment: The date picker format is set by the browser. Different user agents has different formats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I use datetime-local without AM/PM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332520/how-can-i-use-datetime-local-without-am-pm)

Comment: The short answer is you cannot as it is only implementing ISO 8601 date format.  Use JQuery Datapicker for more flexibility https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input type="time"` but It depends on the time format of the user's operating system when the web browser was launched. You can change your OS time format and restart your browser to check.

This doesn't support all browser, if you are working with bootstrap is better to use http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/